# trouble creating a spring tool suite in eclipse

Tags: spring, eclipse

[Workspace SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5LP8.png)

Project not properly created as shown above.

I am new to Spring Boot and Restful. I am trying to create Spring Starter Project but I am not sure if the project is created correctly.

I referred many websites for creating a simple spring-boot and restful project but having trouble in creating it.

Also, I am getting error in pom.xml

```
Error: Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
Project build error: Non-parseable POM /<user>/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.1.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.1.3.RELEASE.pom: start tag not allowed in epilog but got v (position: END_TAG seen ...</build>\n</project>\n <v... @3189:4)    pom.xml /SpringBootCrudRestful  line 1  Maven pom Loading Problem
```

This is the picture below.
Please let me know if I am in the right direction or if there is any problem.

Thanks in advance.

Attaching as per comments: [pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HZkt.png)

**Update 1:**
After some digging, I found out that spring-boot-cli version was 2.0.4.RELEASE(Eclipse-> Preference->Spring tab-> Boot->CLI) but while created the project it was trying to create in 2.1.3.RELEASE.

**Update 2:**
I made changes to my pom.xml and the project was created successfully.
I added the dependency of spring boot new version to pom.xml.

Comment: Can you attach pom. xml file content? It seems there is something wrong in that file

Comment: It's complaining that the `pom.xml` file is unparseable. Show us its contents.

Comment: add pom.xml sreenshot.. its giving error in the first line.